# generic as a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have this method

```
static public <K> float calculateSimilarity(HashMap<K, Float> hashMap1, Class<K> clazz)
```

In the part I call this method it is like this:

```
HashMap<Pair<Long,Long>,Float> newValues1=....; //A.K.A. K is Pair<Long,Long> type.

calculateSimilarity(newValue1, Pair.class); // Doesn't work here!
```

where Pair is

> org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair
>
> A pair consisting of two elements.

Can you please tell me how should I use Pair.class when calling the calculationSimilarity method? Because If I use String as K it worked but Pair here it doesn't work I got compling error.

Comment: Would you like to tell us what the compilation error says, or must we guess?

Comment: Eclipse just say "method XXX  is not applicable for the arguments XXX" nothing else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `HashMap<Pair<Long, Long>>`, type parameter `K` is inferred as `Pair<Long, Long>`. So you need to pass `Class<Pair<Long, Long>>` but you're passing `Class<Pair>`. You need to use appropriate cast:

```
calculateSimilarity(newValue1, (Class<Pair<Long, Long>>)(Class<?>)Pair.class);
```

The cast is required because you can't directly get the required `Class` type using `.class` literal.

Comment: +1 there's that chained cast again. I still love it :)

Comment: Thanks it works but why it needs to cast Pair.class to (Class<?>) first?

Comment: @Tyler: Because it's illegal to cast between two reference types that provably do not overlap. No type (other than the `null` type) can be a subtype of both `Class<Pair<Long, Long>>` and `Class<Pair>`, just like no type can be a subtype of both `List<Object>` and `List<String>`.